# How to create custom event with the shortest way?

Tags: android, kotlin, event-handling, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

There is `CustomWebViewClient` with override function `onPageFinished`. What is the shortest way to notify `MainViewModel` about the function triggered? I mean some event.

I suppose that can use `StateFlow`, something like this:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() { 
    init {
        val client = CustomWebViewClient()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            client.onPageFinished.collect {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}

class CustomWebViewClient() : WebViewClient() {

    private val _onPageFinished = MutableStateFlow("")
    val onPageFinished = _onPageFinished.asStateFlow()

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        _onPageFinished.update { "" }
    }
}
```

But in this case need to transfer unnecessary empty string and will be occurs first call before `onPageFinished` called because `MutableStateFlow` has value. So appear required add some enum or class in order to do filter with `when` keyword.

Maybe is there more shortest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add lambda parameter into CustomWebViewClient constructor that will get called once page is finished.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() { 
    init {
        val client = CustomWebViewClient({handle the event})
    }
}

class CustomWebViewClient(onPageFinished: () -> Unit) : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        onPageFinished()
    }
}
```

Please note that referencing anything from android.* package in a ViewModel is most often a big no-go.

Comment: Can you explain more about referencing? At this time `View` get `Client` from `ViewModel`: `binding.webView.webViewClient = viewModel.client`

Comment: I don't know what you're creating, but what stops you from using WebViewClient in a view layer?

Comment: I base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833748/5894542) answer. The three paragraph from below explain why `View` get referring to `Client` from `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `MutablStateFlow` approach, another option is to also override `onPageStarted` as well and do something like

```
class CustomWebViewClient(): WebViewClient() {
    private val _onPageFinished = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val onPageFinished = _onPageFinished.asStateFlow()
    override fun onPageStarted(
        view: WebView?,
        url: String?,
        favicon: Bitmap?,
    ) {
        _onPageFinished.update { false }
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        _onPageFinished.update { true }
    }
}

class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        val client = CustomWebViewClient()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            client.onPageFinished.collect {
                if (it) {
                    // Do stuff when page is loaded
                } else {
                    // Do stuff when page starts loading
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though ultimately using flows for this is kinda overkill and using the lambda approach suggested by Mieszko Koźma is probably more straight forward.